# Как отменить работающие потоки threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, threading

Пытаюсь отменить запущеные потоки после достижения `timeout` в методе `concurrent.futures.wait`, но программа все равно работает 10 секунд указанные в `if url == "url_3":`

```py
import concurrent.futures
from time import sleep, time

sources = ["url_1", "url_2", "url_3"]

def get_request_header(url: str) -> str:
    if url == "url_1":
        sleep(0.8)
    if url == "url_2":
        sleep(0.9)
    if url == "url_3":
        sleep(10)
    return f"{url}-headers"


start = time()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:

    futures = [executor.submit(get_request_header, url) for url in sources]
    completed, uncompleted = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, timeout=1.5)

    for future in uncompleted:
        future.cancel()

for future in completed:
    print(future.result())

print(time() - start)
```

Если принтануть и проверить состояние после [cancel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel), то оно все еще `running` и собственно он возвращает `False`

```
for future in uncompleted:
    print(future)
    print(future.cancel())
    print(future)
```

Необходимо ограничить работу потоков через `timeout` параметр и что бы не завершенные потоки прекратили работу, что не так?

Также пробовал через `as_completed`, через `map` не предлагать.

Comment: Потоки насколько я помню нельзя "уничтожить" пока код внутри не отработает. Можно сделать выход по флагу, если код работает зациклено, но по итогу он всё равно исполнит все инструкции в блоке. Может вам стоит посмотреть в сторону мультипроцессинга, там есть возможность принудительного завершения потока. Как ещё вариант можно не ставить слип на 10 секунд, а проверять внутри цикла каждые 0.1 в течении 10 секунд на изменения флага и если он изменился то return.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал `return` если объект `uncompleted` стал не пустым, но все равно блок `with` отрабатывает до конца

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как в коментах отметил `@Amgarak` запущенные задачи нельзя отменить.

Но что бы главный поток не блокировался, можно создать `ThreadPoolExecutor` без контекстного менеджера и явно вызвать в конце метод `shutdown` (не завершает выполнение уже запущенных задач) с параметрами `(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)`

```
start = time()

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
try:
    futures = [executor.submit(get_request_header, url) for url in sources]
    completed, uncompleted = concurrent.futures.wait(futures, timeout=1.5)
finally:
    executor.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)

print(time() - start)
```

Output:

```
1.5036067962646484
```

**UPD** *Есть нехороший лайфхак*

Можно обернуть код в функцию и создать демонический поток

```py
def task():
    <предыдущий код>

thread = threading.Thread(target=task, daemon=True)
thread.start()
thread.join(1.5)
```

Далее залезть в модуль `concurrent.futures.thread` и закоментировать строчки ожидания выполения задач и тогда потоки выполняющие запущенные задачи будут отменены.

```py
def _python_exit():
    global _shutdown
    with _global_shutdown_lock:
        _shutdown = True
    items = list(_threads_queues.items())
    for t, q in items:
        q.put(None)
    # for t, q in items:
    #     t.join()
```